# VBA Counting Shapes in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

i want to count how many shapes of one type i have on my sheet and save it to a label.

```
Sub Counter()

Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim i As Integer

For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes
    If shp.Master.Name Like "DV-ED.*" Then
       i = i + 1
        End If
        ActivePage.Shapes("SheetED").Characters.Text = CStr(i)
Next shp
End Sub
```

Problem is, that after the last shape of that type i get an error

> "Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set"

im not very familiar with VBA

Comment: Check out this question and my answer to it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603953/identifying-a-shape-parent-in-visio/28605637#28605637 Does that help you?

Comment: i think it doesnt help me. i just need to solve that runtime error. after last shape it occurs at this line:   If shp.Master.Name Like "DV-ED.*" Then

Comment: How about adding another sanity check before `If shp.Master.Name Like "DV-ED.*" Then`, e.g. `If shp.Master<>Nothing Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before accessing properties like `Name` of an object, make sure the object is set:

```
Sub Counter()

Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim i As Integer

For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes
   If shp.Master<>Nothing Then
      If shp.Master.Name Like "DV-ED.*" Then
        i = i + 1
      End If
      ActivePage.Shapes("SheetED").Characters.Text = CStr(i)
   End If
Next shp
End Sub
```